# use a custom function inside a laravel select

Tags: laravel, function, select

I have a query that needs to use a custom function like is showed below.
The problem is that one of the parameters is a value of another field from the same query.
The function is "calcula_distancia" and "$ofps[0]->latitude" and "$ofps[0]->longitude" are fields from a previus query.
The function needs 4 parameters and the last two are field from $necps that is beeing selected, but I can not retrieve the value from it using just 'participantes.latitude' or even without cotes. It passes a string only, to the function.
So, how can I pass the value from this fields beeing selected to the function?
Tryed to use RAW but not work.
Sorry for the big question. thanks! :-)

```php
use App\Classes\MinhasFuncoes;

$mf = new MinhasFuncoes();

$necps = DB::table('necessidades_part')->where('necessidades_part.id_part',"<>",$id_part)
        ->where(function($query) use ($searchValues){
                foreach ($searchValues as $value) {
                            if(strlen($value)>3){      
                            $query->orwhere('obs','like','%'.($value).'%')
                                ->orwhere('necessidades.descricao','like','%'.($value).'%')
                                ->orwhere('categorias.descricao','like','%'.($value).'%');
                            }
                }
        
        })

    ->join('participantes','necessidades_part.id_part','=','participantes.id')
    ->join('necessidades','necessidades_part.id_nec','=','necessidades.id')
    ->join('categorias','necessidades.id_cat','=','categorias.id')
    ->join('unidades','necessidades.id_unid','=','unidades.id')
    
    ->select('participantes.id as id_part','participantes.nome_part','participantes.latitude',
            'participantes.longitude','participantes.nome_part','necessidades_part.id as id_nec_part',
            'necessidades_part.id_nec','necessidades_part.quant','necessidades_part.data',
            'necessidades_part.obs','necessidades.descricao as desc_nec',
            'categorias.descricao as desc_cat','unidades.descricao as desc_unid',
            $mf->calcula_distancia($ofps[0]->latitude,$ofps[0]->longitude,'participantes.latitude',
            'participantes.longitude').' as distancia')

            ->orderBy('data','desc')
            ->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not execute your PHP function inside of your DB query. you should use MySQL function instead of that or you should fetch results from the database then map your result just in PHP